# CAML Query IN operator not returning the desired results. If I change one Choice column, it stops to appear!

Tags: caml, query

I've a query that goes like this:

```
                <In>
                <FieldRef Name='Industry'/>
                <Values>
                    <Value Type='Text'>Insurance</Value>
                </Values>                 
                </In>
```

I would expect it to be equivalent to this:

```
                <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Industry'/>
                <Value Type='Text'>Insurance</Value>
                </Eq>
```

But the first one returns 3 results and the second one around 400. Also, the column i'm querying against is a Choice one. If I add one value to that column and then remove it, it stops to appear in the first query. Am I missing something? Does In operator works as I supposed?

And, is there any reason for my result to stop appear in my first query after I modify the column? (It keeps not appearing even when I remove the new element, so it's as it was before)

Answer (score 0):

The **In** operator is used to compare the query with multiple dynamic values.

In your case, I would suggest using `<Eq>` with `choice` as a value type instead of `Text` as below

```
<Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Industry'/>
    <Value Type='Choice'>Insurance</Value>
</Eq>
```

> In case, the choice field is MultiChoice, you have to use `<Value Type='MultiChoice'>Insurance</Value>` but in this case, it will return all items that contain **Insurance** word

Comment: Hello, my problem is, I need to do it with an <In>, as there are columns with more than one value. If I do it with an Eq, I would not be getting these results. 

My main question is, shouldn't an "In" operator returns all results with "Insurance" in the Choice column? May I use other column type to do this? 

Right now it is not getting the results it should. I think it's a metadata problem. Could you shed light on this matter? I'm kind of lost! 

Thank you in advance!